# How do I select multiple column ranges using "If Columns" in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this code on a toggle button to hide/show columns in my spreadsheet.

```
Sub Button22_Click()
If Columns("D:E").Hidden = True Then
Columns("D:E").Hidden = False
Else
Columns("D:E").Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

This formula works great for columns **D:E**. The question is, how do I add other columns, both single and ranges, to this formula?  Suppose I need to show/hide **F:K** and **N** as well, with the same button?  I've tried things like ("D:E","F:K") and I get a runtime error. Any help is VERY appreciated.

Comment: Try to post any errors you receive along with your questions.  Errors are the gateway to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Range object.

```
Range("D:E,F:K,N:N").Select
Selection.Hidden = True
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx

**Update:**

Your code should look like this:

```
Sub Button22_Click()
    Range("D:E,F:K,N:N").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, I'm a complete noob at VBA.  How does this solution fit into my existing code?

Answer (score 1):

Just syntax to hide a disjoint set of columns:

```
Sub dural()
   Range("D:E,L:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

This will hide columns **D, E,** and **L**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, I'm a complete noob at VBA.  How does this solution fit into my existing code?